# Send text to excel sheet using winapi

Tags: c#, excel, winapi

I have the following problem. Some application opens an excel file and write data in there automatically every few seconds.The excel file is opened exclusive and I can't accessing from another application. The content of the cells are changed pretty fast so I need to read/write some cell content inside that opened file. When i say open I mean that the excel application is open and I am looking at it.

Is it possible to use winapi from a c# application, to send message to the opened excel, in order to fill a certain cell or to read a certain cell. I need to try this way since the file is locked, so I am thinking to access it using this manner.

Get the excel window handle, read a cell , send a text to a cell.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: I am not sure that will work, because it requires access to the file as far as I can see. While in my case, the file is opened already exclusively by another process. I need to send my text in a specific cell, while the excel document is already opened.

Answer (score 0):

You can try DDE (Dynamic Data Exchange) API to interact with Excel. Example, DDESend() function used to do DDE conversation with excel. For more information, visit

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/ddesend-function-HA001228822.aspx

Comment: This might work, but is difficult to find a concrete example...will continue looking.

Answer (score 0):

If the instance of Excel is running on the same machine as your C# app then you can use the following to get that instance. I use it in order to grab a user's running instance of Excel in order to read data from their open spreadsheet.

```
private Excel.Application GetCurrentVersionOfExcel()
{
    Excel.Application xlApp;

    // Try to get the currently-running Excel application

    try
    {
        xlApp = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
    }
    catch
    {
        // In case there isn't a version running or the current version hasn't registered itself with the Running Object Table

        xlApp = null;
    }

    return xlApp;
}
```

If that doesn't quite get you there I also have code to go through all open workbook processes and find the one you're looking for. It's quite long so if it's something you think might work for you then let me know and I'll post it. Basically it works by grabbing window handles and checking the child windows to see if they're workbooks.

Comment: Hi Sid, i will try that right away. The only thing that concerns me is that a certain file might be locked...but will test that now.

Comment: @IftemiAlin You're grabbing the Excel instance, not the file itself, so file locking shouldn't be an issue. It'll be almost as if you're imitating the user interacting with the instance of Excel that they themselves opened.